# How to access `PromiseValue` in axios `response` in VueJs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, promise, axios, vue-component

I am trying to show `client` information details in the modal. After clicking `@click="showDetails(props.row.id)"`.

I am using `axios.get` in method and returning the data. Now, It's returning the data as **PromiseValue** object. How to access `PromiseValue` to show the value in HTML. Would someone help me please to solve the problem! I am trying like below -

```
<button @click="showDetails(props.row.id)"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></button>
```

And in **script-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  import axios from 'axios';
  export default {
    data(){
        return{
            leftPanelVisiblity: false,
            singleData: '',            }
    },
    methods:{
        showDetails(id){
            let b = axios.get('/api/clients/'+id)
                      .then(function (response) {
                        return response.data;

                      }).catch(error => {
                            alert(error);
                      });
            //console.log(b);
            this.singleData = b;
            this.leftPanelVisiblity = true
        },
    }
  }
</script>
```

[image]

And finally, I want to access or show the data in the `leftPanelVisiblity` modal like -

`<p>Name: {{ this.singleData.name }}</p>`

Or

`<p>Name: {{ this.singleData.email }}</p>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign the Axios call to a variable while using Promises (unless you are using await/async).

Instead you should be running the logic within the `then` callback. Otherwise to the synchronous nature of JavaScript it will run before the request has completed. Your code should look something like this:

```
methods:{
  showDetails(id){
    axios.get('/api/clients/'+row.id).then(response => {

      //Logic goes here
      this.singleData = response.data
      this.leftPanelVisibility = true

    }).catch(error => {
      alert(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `showDetails(id){
                axios.get('/api/clients/'+id)
                          .then(function (response) {
                            let b = response.data;
                            this.singleData = b;
                            this.leftPanelVisiblity = true
                          }).catch(error => {
                                alert(error);
                          });        
   },` .... but getting this error -`TypeError: Cannot set property 'singleData' of undefined`

Comment: @RashedHasan I have updated my response. It is now using short arrow functions to the `this` scope does not change in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a variable the response of your axios:

```
 showDetails(id){
        axios.get('/api/clients/'+id)
                  .then(function (response) {
                      this.singleData = response.data;
                  }).catch(error => {
                        alert(error);
                  });
        console.log(this.sigleData);

        this.leftPanelVisiblity = true
    },
```

Comment: It's getting `TypeError: Cannot set property 'singleData' of undefined` error.